# Smoothness of family of distributions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Let $X$ be a compact manifold. Denote by $\mathscr{D}^\prime(X \times X)$ the space of tempered distributions on the cartesian product $X \times X$. Given two test functions $\varphi, \psi \in \mathscr{D}(X)$, an element $T \in \mathscr{D}^\prime(X \times X)$ can be evaluated at the function $\varphi \otimes \psi$ on $X \times X$ defined by $(\varphi \otimes \psi)(x, y) := \varphi(x) \psi(y)$.

Suppose now that $T_\lambda \in \mathscr{D}^\prime(X \times X)$, $\lambda \in\mathbb{R}$, is a family of distributions such that
$$\lambda \longmapsto T_\lambda[\varphi \otimes \psi]$$
is a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ for any two $\varphi, \psi \in \mathscr{D}(X)$.

**Q:** Does it follow that also the function
$$ \lambda \longmapsto T_\lambda[\Phi]$$
is smooth for every $\Phi \in \mathscr{D}(X \times X)$?

Comment: My rapid guess is the answer is yes. I think the compact hypothesis is a distraction and should be removed. I would try first $X=\mathbb{R}$ and if it works, it should adapt to reasonable smooth manifolds (second countable). For $X=\mathbb{R}$, I would also first consider the analogue for $\mathscr{S},\mathscr{S}'$ instead of $\mathscr{D},\mathscr{D}'$. The condition on the functions of $\lambda$ being smooth, i.e., being in $\mathscr{E}$, should be replaced in the analogue by being in $\mathscr{O}_{\rm M}$, then the multiplier space characterization of the latter and the Kernel Theorem...

Comment: ..might be enough.

Comment: If the answer is yes, then the family $T_\lambda$ for $\lambda$ in a compact set should be pointwise bounded on $\mathscr D(X\times X)$ and hence equicontinuous, which roughly means that the continuity estimates for $T_\lambda$ only depend on a fixed number of derivatives with uniform constants. On the other hand, if you have this kind of equicontinuity a priori for $T_\lambda$ and all of its derivatives w.r.t. $\lambda$, an approximation argument might yield the desired result.

Comment: Another guess: for good behavior one needs the kernel $T_{\lambda}(x,y)$ to be a distribution in $(\lambda,x,y)$. I don't yet see how this follows from the hypotheses. Perhaps using the uniform boundedness principle?

Comment: In other words: the hypotheses define a bilinear map $\mathscr{D}(X)^2\rightarrow \mathscr{E}(\mathbb{R})$, but do they imply this bilinear form is continuous?

Comment: Your question has been answered and this is rather OT but it might be of interest that your result has only marginally to do with distributions and more with criteria for smoothness of operator valued functions and with properties of nuclear spaces which have been known for over 60 years.  Here is an example: Let $E$ and $F$ be nuclear $F$-spaces, $T$ a mapping, say from the line, into the tensor product of the dual spaces.Then $T$ is smooth ($C^\infty$) if and only if the same is true of the scalar functions $s\mapsto T(s)(x\otimes y)$ for each $x$ and $y$ in $E$ and $F$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof using convenient analysis:
By the kernel theorem $\mathscr{D}^\prime(X \times X) = L(\mathscr{D}(X),\mathscr{D}^\prime(X))$ and by 
[The Convenient setting of Global Analysis](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf),  5.18 (which is just the uniform boundedness principle) and 2.14 we have 
\begin{align*}
&\lambda\mapsto T_\lambda(\Phi) \in  \mathbb R \text{ is }C^\infty 
\quad\forall \Phi \in \mathscr{D}(X \times X)
\\
\iff &\lambda\mapsto T_\lambda \in  \mathscr{D}^\prime(X \times X)
\text{ is }C^\infty \quad &\text{by 2.14}
\\
\iff &\lambda\mapsto T_\lambda \in L(\mathscr{D}(X),\mathscr{D}^\prime(X)) 
\text{ is }C^\infty 
\\ 
\iff & \lambda\mapsto T_\lambda(\varphi) \in \mathscr{D}^\prime(X) 
\text{ is }C^\infty\quad \forall \varphi\in \mathscr{D}(X) &\text{by 5.18}
\\
\iff & \lambda\mapsto T_\lambda(\varphi)(\psi) \in \mathbb R 
\text{ is }C^\infty \quad\forall \varphi,\psi\in \mathscr{D}(X) \quad &\text{by 2.14}
\end{align*}
Up to Frechet spaces convenient smoothness equals each other reasonable notion, but beyond it differs. A short description of convenient analysis can be found in 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenient_vector_space).

Comment: Interesting. I thought you would contribute an answer because, if I understood correctly, convenient analysis builds on the notion of smooth curves in LCTVS's. Do you know if $T_{\lambda}(x,y)$ belongs to $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}\times X\times X)$?

Comment: @ Abdelmalek Abdesselam $T_\lambda(x,y)$ belongs to $C^\infty(\mathbb R, \mathscr{D}^\prime(X \times X) = C^\infty(\mathbb R)\bar\otimes \mathscr{D}^\prime(X \times X)\subset \mathscr{D}^\prime(\mathbb R\times X \times X)$.